# Differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt} = kx^2$ prove that I have all the solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In the book *Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems* by Edwards and Penney, section 1.1, question 43, a differential equation is provided:

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = kx^2\
$$

and a solution:

$$
x(t)=\frac{1}{C-kt}.
$$

The question then says "Determine by inspection a solution of the initial value problem $x'=kx^2, x(0)=0.$"

I reason that since the provided solution never equals $0$, I can safely ignore it.  Also, if $x=0$, then $x'=0$, which means that only the functions which *might* be solutions are ones that have a local min or max at the point $(0,0)$.

The answer in the back of the book is given as the identically zero function.  This makes me squint, since while that clearly is a solution, I don't see how to prove that it's the only one.  At this point, I realize that the question does say **a** solution, and not **every** solution, so I guess it works as an answer to the question, but now I'm still left wondering if the identically zero function is in fact the only solution that satisfies that initial condition, and more particularly, how to prove it, if it's true.

I see how to achieve the solution for all $x$ where $x\neq 0$, so that part is clear to me.  I just don't see how to go from "the point $(t,0)$ must be a local extremum if it solves $x$" to "$x$ is identically $0$", or actually, if that conclusion is even true.

Comment: For any autonomous first-order ODE $x' = f(x)$ the constant functions $x(t) = x_0$ where $f(x_0) = 0$, i. e. the zeros of $f$, are solutions. These cannot be obtained by any value of $C$ in the general solution. So indeed with just the general solution $x(t) = (C-kt)^{-1}$ you do *not* have all the solutions of the ODE.

Answer (score 1):

There is a well known theorem giving conditions for existence and uniqueness of first order differential equations $ y' = F(x, y), y(x_0) = y_0 $.

The statement of the theorem is that if $F(x, y)$ be a real-valued function continuous on some rectangle $ R = \{ (x, y) | |x - x_0| \leq a, |y - y_0| \leq b\}$, and $ \partial F / \partial y$ is continuous on $ R$, then there exists an interval $ I = [x_0 - h, x_0 + h] $, $h \leq a$, such that the initial value problem has a unique solution.

Comment: So...the reasoning is that since $x(t)=0$ is always a solution for every $t$, then since that solution is unique, no other function which is a solution can hit the same point?

Comment: Sort of. All this theorem initially gives you is a small interval (-h, h) for which the solution is unique. You can then extend this by repeated application of the theorem to all of R.